# Programatically create skeleton in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, inverse-kinematics

I am loading a model of a mechanism (e.g. a robot arm) in Three.js. Sadly the models I am using don't have a skeleton, but I have the locations, axes and so on of the joints. In order to use e.g. inverse kinematic solvers like Three-IK, I want to create a skeleton from these parameters. Since I want to use many different models I would prefer to not create the skeletons by hand but in code.

I have been trying for over a week now to create a valid bone structure from these values that reflects the model, but nothing succeeded. For example, if I create a chain of bones using the positions of the joints I get a very long skeleton which in no way matches the positions I used.

```
let boneParent;
let bonepos = [];
let bones = [];
model.traverse(child => {
    switch(child.type) {
        case "joint":
            let p = new Vector3();
            child.getWorldPosition(p);
            bonepos.push(p);

            let bone = new Bone();
            boneParent && boneParent.add(p);
            bone.worldToLocal(p.clone());
            bone.position.copy(p);
            bone.rotation.copy(child.rotation);
            bone.scale.copy(child.scale);

            boneParent = bone;
            bones.push(bone);
            break;
    }
});
showPoints(scene, bonepos, 0xff0000);

const skeletonHelper = new SkeletonHelper(bones[0]);
skeletonHelper.visible = true;
scene.add(skeletonHelper);
```

The code above results in the screenshot below. The red markers are the positions I get from the robot joints, the line snaking into the distance is the skeleton as visualized by the SkeletonHelper.

[image: Robot with very bad bones]

**So my question is this**: it seems like I don't understand well enough how bones are handled in Three.js. How can I create a skeleton that reflects my existing model from its joint locations and orientations?

Thanks in advance!

**For future visitors:** [Rocksi is open source!](https://github.com/ndahn/Rocksi/)

Comment: Hello Managarm,  I am currently working on similar problem using a URDF robot model, and I am trying to use off the shelf IK solvers but they use bones, by any chance do you have code that you could share ?

Comment: Hey @JorgeVilchis, I do indeed :D Check out https://github.com/ndahn/Rocksi for the latest version!

Comment: Managarm, I took a look into above git repo,  I was nicely surprised ,  the whole reason I am trying to incorporate three js bones and skeleton to a URDF robot model is to use CCD and FABRIK IK solvers !

Comment: Do you have have linkedin account ?  Do you mind if I send you direct message over there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some fiddling around I found a solution:

```
let root = new Bone();
let parent = root;
let pos = new Vector3();

for (let joint of robot.arm.movable) {
    let link = robot.getLinkForJoint(joint);
    link.getWorldPosition(pos);
    
    let bone = new Bone();
    parent.add(bone);
    parent.lookAt(pos);
    parent.updateMatrixWorld();  // crucial for worldToLocal!
    bone.position.copy(bone.worldToLocal(pos));
        
    parent = bone;
}
```

The important part is to **call updateMatrixWOrld() after lookAt()** so that `bone.worldToLocal()` works correctly. Also `lookAt()` saves a lot of matrix hassles :)

Comment: @Managam can you please refer to the documentation of `getLinkForJoint` I can't find this function documentation!

Comment: @Bilal That line is part of my project, see [here](https://github.com/ndahn/Rocksi/blob/fb37baf7f808f91c4e9785c9c00e74cb643375a6/src/simulator/robots/robotbase.js#L270). [Rocksi](https://github.com/ndahn/Rocksi) is open source!

Answer (score 0):

> child.getWorldPosition(p);

I'm afraid it's incorrect to apply the position in world space to `Bone.position` which represents the position in *local* space.

> boneParent = bone;

This line looks problematic, too. A bone can have multiple child elements. It seems to me that this use case is not considered of your code.

Comment: Local space is global space if there is no parent yet :) But I tried parenting first and translating to local space, too.
Single parents are okay as long as it's a single kinematic chain!

Comment: But you are introducing a hierarchy when using `add()` so your code is definitely not correct. I suggest you demonstrate the issue with a live example.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I have added a more complete example and a screenshot!